# css - how to position <li> in horizontal <ul>?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have `section`, which contains horizontal `ul`, which contains four `li`'s,
as following:

```css
#header-strip ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 4vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: grey;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#header-strip li {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<section id="header-strip">
    <ul>
      <li>meant to be left</li
      ><li>meant to be centered</li
      ><li>meant to be just before last</li
      ><li>meant to be right</li
      >
    </ul>
  </section>
```

**Requirements:**
- first item at left with some small percentage offset of screen edge
- second item centered in the middle
- third item to be at right, with some percentage space between to fourth
- fourth item at right, with percentage offset from screen edge

I am able to position `li`'s with basic `justify-content: space-between;`, but don't know how to position it the custom way.

It should look like this:

[image: menu]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply change the margin of the second element and make it `auto`

*As a side note: with flexbox you don't need to worry about whitespace and no need to define element as `inline`*

```css
#header-strip ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color:#ffff;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#header-strip li {
 margin:0 2%;
}

#header-strip li:nth-child(2) {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<section id="header-strip">
  <ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
    <li>D</li>

  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks very much:). One additional question. It seems to me that the middle element is centered between first and third element, but I want it to be centered in the middle of the strip itself. So, how to do it ?

Comment: @milkamar yes right, actually it's centred between both element ... if you want a perfect centring you will need few *hack*. Here is an example : https://jsfiddle.net/thdnmyLx/

Answer (score 0):

if you are using flexbox:

```
<section id="header-strip">
    <ul>
      <li>meant to be left</li
      ><li class="fill">meant to be centered</li
      ><li>meant to be just before last</li
      ><li>meant to be right</li
      >
    </ul>
  </section>
```

//css

```
.fill {
    flex-grow: 2;
}
```